# How do I finish developing this? yz dx+2xz dy+xy dz=0

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have this pfaff equation $yz dx+ 2xz dy+ xy dz=0$ and try to solve it as follows
$$Rot F=\begin{bmatrix}{i}&{j}&{k}\\{\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}}}&{\frac{{\partial }}{{\partial y}}}&{\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial z}}}\\{yz}&{2xz}&{xy}\end{bmatrix}=\left(\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial y}}(xy)-\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial z}}(2xz);-((\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}}(xy)-\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial z}}(yz));(\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial x}}(2xz)-\frac{{\partial}}{{\partial y}}(yz)\right)$$
$$Rot F=\left(x-2x;-(y-y);2z-z\right)=(-x;0;z)$$
$$F\cdot{Rot F}=(yz;2xz;xy)\cdot{(-x;0;z)}=-xyz+2xz\cdot{0}+xyz=0$$
$F$ is integrable and it is also known that
$F=\triangledown f $ or grad$ f$
$$\frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial x}}=yz \qquad \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial y}}=2xz \qquad \frac{{\partial f}}{{\partial z}}=xy$$
from this part I don't know what else to do :(, i need to find f

Comment: you cannot solve it without multiplying it first by an integrating factor $\mu$, since the obvious necessary conditions needed to have an exact form are not satisfied...

Comment: Note: You can write your Pfaff equation as $$\frac{d(xyz)}{xyz}=-\frac{dy}{y}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$yz dx+ 2xz dy+ xy dz=0$$
$$y^2z dx+ 2xyz dy+ xy^2 dz=0$$
$$d(xy^2z)=0$$
$$xy^2z=C$$